What's the difference between the small thin replacements and the larger blades for a Bosch 1594 electric hand planer?
What's the difference between the small thin replacements and the larger blades on a Bosch 1594 electric hand planer?
Pages 9 and 10 of the bosch manual detail replacing the two different types of blades, but I don't see where it says why you would choose the small (mini carbide) or the large blades. The large blades can be purchased either as HSS or steel with a carbide insert.
Here is the link to the pages,
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/19286/Bosch-1594.html?page=9#manual
It looks like the planer can take either type of blade. Why would you choose one vs the other, i.e., the small blade vs the larger blade?
picture that shows:

large single blade

single small blade

single small blade holder

completely assembled single small blade with holder assembly




If you are referring to carbide vs. steel planer blades, here is another good answer to that question:  https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/carbide-vs-high-speed-steel-in-jointer-blade

It's a matter of availability, cost, and suitability for the job. Your planer accommodates both styles, so you have the option of using either.
During the '90s planer makers started using the disposable carbide inserts rather than the full-size blades. The former are obviously cheaper to produce than full-size blades with carbide. They're also double-sided, so if you don't hit something big and hard and shatter them you can flip them for extended life. (Actually, you can use a shattered insert if you don't mind a tiny imperfection in the resulting surface.)
Unless you're working exclusively with soft, clean wood, you want carbide. If you're doing rough framing you probably want HSS so they don't crack up so easily if you nick a nail. Buy and use what's appropriate, cost-effective, and available.
